# dllexport an all-inline class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

Consider a simple class, which consists of only inlined member functions. For example:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Point2D {
public:
    typedef Point2D<T1,T2> ThisType;
    typedef T1 Tx;
    typedef T2 Ty;
    T1 x;
    T2 y;
    inline Point2D() : x(0), y(0) {}
    inline Point2D(T1 nx, T2 ny) : x(nx), y(ny) {}
    inline Point2D(const Point2D& b) : x(b.x), y(b.y) {}
    inline Point2D& operator=(const Point2D& b) { x=b.x; y=b.y; return *this; }
    inline ~Point2D() {}
};

typedef Point2D<int,int> Int2;
```

When an object of type `Int2` is used within another class (say, class `MyClass`, member `Int2 point`) which I want to export to a DLL, I get the following warning:

warning C4251: 'MyClass::point' : class 'Point2D' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'MyClass'

However, if I put `__declspec(dllexport)` in the definition of 'Point2D' as the warning suggests (which seems silly to me as all the function are inlined, plus it is a template, [see SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876279/c-inline-functions-with-dllimport-dllexport)), I get the following error when trying to use the DLL in another poject:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall lwin::Point2D::Point2D(int,int)" ...

Note, the definition of `Point2D` is given in a header which is visible for all the projects.

What should I do? Skip the `dllexport` and ignore the warning? Or is there some neat trick which can avoid this compiler confusion?

Comment: You got the warning because you forgot about the copy constructor and assignment operator that the compiler auto-generates.  Just add them to the class or ignore the warning.

Comment: Good catch! Fixed. But the problem remains...

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Int2` member of `MyClass` with `Int2*` member to solve this problem. Create `Int2` instance in `MyClass` constructor and delete in `MyClass` destructor.

Templated class cannot be exported, so you cannot declare it as  `__declspec(dllexport)`. C4251 is shown, because container class size may be different, if Dll and its client are compiled with different compilation options, which causes undefined behavior. On the other side, a pointer has always the same size.

Comment: If I replaced all `Int2` into `Int2*` (and alike), use `new` and `delete`, that will be ultimately a big performance loss! No way to get around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only way I know to solve this problem. You can ignore this warning only if both Dll and all its clients are always compiled together as part of some system. Of course, with the same compiler options.

Comment: @Alex: You need that for exported classes anyway.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - are you talking about ignoring this warning? Well, I never do this in my own projects, possibly this advise was incorrect.

Comment: Without better solution, if performance is critical, I would replace Point2D with non-template class.

Comment: If I need it for `Int2`, `Float2`, `UChar2`, etc... template comes in handy. Alternative is a really ugly macro. But for the need of dllexport/dllimport I don't really understand why macro would be better than template. Both template and macros operate at compile time, while dllexport is needed for run-time linking so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `__declspec(dllexport)` / `__declspec(dllimport)` respectively to each inline method. This would be an error for non-template class, but template classes / functions seem to require adding this per-method too.