# How to keep calls inlined but avoid compiler warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have a class, which is widely used in all code in my software. This class is point abstraction with some geometry functions and it is templated by type of coordinates, for example long or double. If this point is passed between dynamic libraries I get compiler warning *C4252:  class 'Point' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'OtherClass'* but code works well and fast because all library have the same compilation settings.

Since our policy is to have no warnings at all we decided to mark two widely used template specializations dll-exported like this (in header with template):

```
 template class __declspec(dllexport) Point<long>;
 template class __declspec(dllexport) Point<double>;
```

But now compiler replaces all inlines with common function calls and because of this class is heavily used our code became much slower.

The question is: Is there any way to keep calls inlined in each library where it is used but still pass data between dlls and avoid warnings?

We use Microsoft VC++ 2012 compiler.

Comment: In my experience if speed is an issue I have achieved better performance by using statically linked code rather than DLLs, for exactly the reasons you describe, however, on retrospect I think thjere may be some way to achieve what you are saying, though I suspect benchmarking will still show statically linked code to be faster.  I am looking into forcing dlls to be memory resident at load time, so that a similar performance to the inbuilt/static linked code can be achieved.  I will get back to you later on today:)

Comment: The problem is not in change of calls from static to dynamic but in change of inline functions to common called function. As soon as you mark your class/function dll export you won't get any inline function anymore.

Comment: Yep, that comes back to static/dynamic linking: you cant `inline` code at compilation if it is in a DLL as the compiler doesn't know the specifics of the code behind the function.  The source has to be available at compilation to inline into the calling location, at which point a dll becomes unnecesssary, as the code is already in the exe.

Comment: I know DLLs make code updates much more straightforward, however for raw speed there has to be some trade-off: I have had `exe`s that weigh in at ove 500MB however, they were required for the ability to run as fast as possible, when speed is not an issue and ease of maintenance/memory footprint is, DLLs can almost always save the day:)

Comment: Class source is indeed available at compilation phase, but the problem is that it is passed between other DLLs. Yes, it works, but gives warnings. So we are ok with current architecture, but I'm thinking about warning disapearing.

Comment: Ahh, i thought speed was an issue here too, if all you need is to get rid of the warning, the simplest way I can think of is to add `#pragma warning( disable : 4252 )` to your code and it will remove the warning

Answer (score 0):

In my experience if speed is an issue I have achieved better performance by using statically linked code/header only `inline` and `fastcall` code rather than `DLL`s, for exactly the reasons you describe, however, on retrospect I think there may be some way to achieve what you are saying, though I suspect benchmarking will still show statically linked code to be faster.

I am looking into forcing `DLL`s to be memory resident at load time (and can indeed do this as per the article **[here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2006/10/09/Preventing-a-DLL-from-being-unloaded-by-the-app-that-uses-it.aspx)**) so that a similar performance to the inlined/static linked code can be achieved.

This seems to work at first, however if the memory where the `DLL` is loaded is paged at any point, it will become as slow as accessing `DLL` code dynamically.

Until I have researched further methods of linking to `DLL`s I would personally recommend **[inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) [fastcall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#fastcall)** code if that is an option, although this will cause the executable to become larger, and may impact your release if the memory footprint is an issue.

As a quick fix for the two lines you mentioned above you could try changing:

```
template class __declspec(dllexport) Point<long>;
template class __declspec(dllexport) Point<double>;
```

to

```
extern template class __declspec(dllexport) Point<long>;
extern template class __declspec(dllexport) Point<double>;
```

which should hopefully remove the issue you are having. (more information on doing this available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;168958), utilised on that page to export instanciations of STL classes or objects containing STL classes which seems to be the same issue).

However the principle of inlining (a compilation stage "optimisation") innately sits in opposition to export/import from a DLL: the former optimises for speed by bolting everything together in one package, the latter optimises for memory footprint/modularity by separating the code into distinct smaller bundles that can be called on at need.

**Notes:**

1. `fastcall` places one or more of the arguments into registers,
   thereby reducing the number of memory calls required to execute.

   - For MSoft and GCC you get the most noticeable speed benefits when you have only 2 arguments.
   - Borland compilers will allow up to 3 registers/arguments to be used
2. Note also that the inline keyword does not guarantee that code will
   be inlined, it is merely an extremely strong suggestion to the
   compiler, however other optimisation flags could remove it or inline
   other parts which you had not marked as inline.

---

Hope this helps, but as always, if you need any more information/help, please let me know. :)

Comment: support for inline/dllexport/dllimport not being compatible also found [elsewhere on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876279/c-inline-functions-with-dllimport-dllexport)