# C++ Module Definition File header inline symbol

Tags: c++, dllexport

I am using a module definition file (.def) in Visual Studio 2013 to selectively export symbols to generate an import library. I can't seem to export functions that are completely inlined in the header. I do not wish to use `declspec(dllexport)` as it makes reversing my application easier, since every dllexported function will have its original signature. Comparison: dllexport (left) vs .def file (right): ![1]´. In this case the whole "Obj_AI_Base" class is dllexported. Short: I do not want reversers to know that the function located at (e.g.) 0x123456 is named obj_AI_Base::GetHealth(), but still make it accessible for 3rd party API.

GameObject.h:

```
class GameObject
{
    inline float Health()
    {
        return 1000;
    }
};
```

I now wish to export the `Health()` method.

The symbol for this method looks as following (exported from dumbin /exports):

```
?Health@GameObject@Native@MyTool@@QAEMXZ
```

Inserted it into my .def file:

```
LIBRARY MyTool
EXPORTS
   ?Health@GameObject@Native@MyTool@@QAEMXZ @1 NONAME
```

Will result in an unresolved external symbol error, despite the Method being inlined in the header file. A solution for this is to move the Method body into a .cpp file.

GameObject.h:

```
class GameObject
{
     float Health();
};
```

GameObject.cpp:

```
class GameObject
{
     GameObject::Health()
     {
         return 1000;
     }
};
```

This will result in the .def file to work as expected. Since this project has a lot of those properties, whose Method body is mostly always just 1 row long this is not a solution for me. Why does the compiler not find the symbol when the Method body is defined in the header, but with `__declspec(dllexport)` it works just fine?

Comment: `I do not wish to use declspec(dllexport) as it reveals the name of my methods.` FYI: Open up your import library in a hex editor. You'll find that the names of your methods are already there. How the import library gets built (either with an explicit .def file or with `__declspec(dllexport)` doesn't change what goes into it.

Comment: Since when does the import library (.lib) gets shipped at deploy? I just want exports to have "MyLib._1" instead of "MyLib.GameObject.GetHealth" as export name, which is done by the [NONAME] attribute in the .def file. Unfortunate that it does not work with .h only methods...

Comment: You don't give people an import library. And you don't tell people what the names of your methods are. I'm guessing you don't give them a header either. So... how do you communicate to your user what `MyLib._1` actually does? How do they reconstitute an entire exported *class* at the other end? I think you're taking secrecy way too far.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my fault. I did not mean to hide the method name. I have edited the first part of my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you're using .def files instead of `__declspec(dllexport)` doesn't mean that the [rules about exporting inline functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876279/c-inline-functions-with-dllimport-dllexport) do not apply to you.

The reason you can't export an explicitly `inline` function is because it's inline, not because of how you export it. The function does not have a single definition in the .dll that can be exported. So neither a .def file nor an explicit `dllexport` attribute can export it.